# How to locate Altium libraries

Tags: altium

I want to use an ECS Crystal in my schematic and PCB layout in Altium, but I cannot find any downloadable libraries for ECS crystals despite ECS Crystal Oscillator. IntLib clearly being listed as an available library [on Altium's website](http://www.altium.com/community/libraries/altium-designer-libraries/en/altium-designer-library-list.cfm).

How do I locate and download these libraries?

Comment: Have you asked Altium?

Comment: Here? http://www.altium.com/community/libraries/altium-designer-libraries/altium-designer-footprint-libraries/en/altium-designer-footprint-libraries_home.cfm

Comment: Altium has repositories in their Altium LIVE system for many devices, but it is possible that they don't have the specific one you're looking for. Try and find the right footprint since this might be common. Creating a schematic symbol is very easy. Just copy it from another similar crystal.

Comment: @dextOrb: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

They will almost certainly already be installed. You can either use the library tab and do a search, or look in the folder where all the libraries are installed for the ECS folder:

[image: Altium ECS Folder]